# Error in installing psycopg2==2.6.1

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to run

```
 pip install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

but I get the error of

```
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and

```
 Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

and finally

```
Command "/home/arpan/ArpanMangal/virtualenvmnts/Heroku/heroku-arpan/bin/python
-u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Hs26Hx/psycopg2/
setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace
('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /tmp/pip-Y6fwIc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally
-managed --compile --install-headers /home/arpan/ArpanMangal/virtualenvmnts/
Heroku/heroku-arpan/include/site/python2.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1
in /tmp/pip-build-Hs26Hx/psycopg2
```

I am installing psycopg2=2.6.1 as a part of requirment.txt file for deploying my app on Heroku.
Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the following dependencies
`sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev`